# Would you face any problems if you have two analytics (Crashlytics and AppDynamics) in your iOS codebase?

Tags: ios, swift, analytics, crashlytics, appdynamics

For a period of time we might want to have the two analytics together. Could this be problematic? Would it be degrade the speed? Would there be any fight between who captures the crash log?!

Comment: It's a simple question. The answers are also given. Not sure why anyone thinks this is too broad. I just needed to know if someone has done this beforeBoth answers here are short empirical evidence to suitable for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** : I would strongly suggest removing the unused one (or the one you don't prefer) from your code. For reasons, like :
1. It will increase project size which in turn will increase your bundle size.
2. Messy code.
3. There is no point checking two different analytics.
4. While third person is understanding the code, he would waste his time in understanding which will lead to confusion.

I might be missing other reasons.

**Second** : To answer your question, it should work fine. I did the same in one of my projects, where initially I was using **Hockey Crash reporting**. But then client asked to use **Crashlytics**. I didn't remove Hockey SDK immediately. Though this worked fine and both reported the issues, but soon I removed Hockey SDK from the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Crashlytics and Google Analytics together without any issue. All the logging is done in a background process so I don't think you will notice any speed degradation but the app is technically doing more work so there is some sort of performance hit.

I haven't seen any issues with the crashlog. Analytics libraries just write the crashlogs to a file and then send them the next time the user opens your app. They are not affecting how the actually crashes are handled by the operating system so there shouldn't be any issue with them conflicting.